# JavaScript: How to access a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have created a multidimensional array, by pushing arrays inside anothers, but now im unable to retrieve the data from it, i have a variable containing it, but now i need to process it and i cant get the values by non of the ways below:

1

```
obj = JSON.parse(myArrayVariable);
alert(obj[0].origin);
```

2

```
alert(myArrayVariable[0]["origin"]);
```

I 've tryed al lot of other ways but all of then gave the same result, "UNDEFINED", I really hate this word. I'm not in a rush but it makes me curious because i' ve been trying this for couple of days and I'm stuck here.

Can anybody give me a hand? thanks stackers!

The array looks like this

```
[
    [
        {
            "origin": "4",
            "destination": "0",
            "scales": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "option": 1,
            "origin": "4",
            "destination": "3",
            "line": "l3",
            "direction": "3",
            "stops": "4,3",
            "stopcount": 2
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "option": 1,
            "origin": "3",
            "destination": "0",
            "line": "l2",
            "direction": "0",
            "stops": "3,2,0",
            "stopcount": 3
        },
        {
            "option": 2,
            "origin": "3",
            "destination": "0",
            "line": "l0",
            "direction": "0",
            "stops": "3,0",
            "stopcount": 2
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: You have an extra set of brackets around the data, so it's 2 arrays. To access it you would need `myVar[0][0].origin`

Comment: It Worked fine! The answer was there all the timee. Thanks, so is that a 3d array?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to flatten this `array of array` (multi-dimensional array)

```
function flatten(arr) {
    var self=this;
    return arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
        return acc.concat(val.constructor === Array ? self.flatten(val) : val);
    },[]);
  }
```

in order to get an one-dimensional `array`:

```
flatten( myArrayVariable )
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

At this point you have it

```
flatten(arr)[0]["origin"]
"4"
```

Depending of what you have to do you can use a `forEach`

```
flatten(arr).forEach(function(item) { console.log( item ) })
```

to traverse it:

```
Object {origin: "4", destination: "0", scales: 1}
Object {option: 1, origin: "4", destination: "3", line: "l3", direction: "3"…}
Object {option: 1, origin: "3", destination: "0", line: "l2", direction: "0"…}
Object {option: 2, origin: "3", destination: "0", line: "l0", direction: "0"…}
```

Comment: seems like a lot of extra work just to get `var flattened =myVar[0]`

Comment: @charlietfl well better to be generic never knows maybe he has nested structures like `[1,2,[1,2],[3],[4,5]]` etc.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of that ... would be like suggesting need to do this all the time.... *"just in case"*